# Why are FSDataOutputStream's hsync and getPos functions out of sync?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink

I have an application that uses `FSDataOutputStream` to write data to HDFS.

In order to write that data I use `FSDataOutputStream`'s `hflush` function. In order to obtain the number of bytes that have been written I use `FSDataOutputStream`'s `getPos` function.

For some reason after `hflush` has been called, `getPos` returns the wrong file size most of the time (sometimes it is correct).

My understanding is that when I call `hflush`, and after that when I call `getPos`, the file size in HDFS has to be equal (in bytes) to what `getPos` returns, but `getPos` always returns something greater! As though half of the file is still stuck in some buffer and hasn't reached a physical disk...

I read about the `hsync` function of `FSDataOutputStream`. I started using `hsync` instead of `hflush`, because it guarantees that the data will not be buffered and will be written to disk.

But the problem still persists, it is very rare now, but I still have the same issue. 10% of the time, when I call `hsync`, and then `getPos`, the file size in HDFS is less than what `getPos` returns.

Why is this happening and how can I synchronize `getPos` with `hsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `hsync` with the `SyncFlag.UPDATE_LENGTH` argument. [Why is hsync() not flushing my hdfs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231105/why-is-hsync-not-flushing-my-hdfs-file)